MOSFET switching efficiency in SPWM DC to AC inverter

After a look in deep in the switching curves of the gates, and I am wondering if switching is acceptable for work MOSFET in SPWM H bridge LF inverter.
I would like your general opinion on all points and your suggestion for some improvement.
Choice 1:Totem pole outputs directly at 6,8 r.

Choice 2:I add a 1 ohm resistor and bypass diode at totem pole output for slow down the falls and result is this:

With the 2 choice the rise here became like this:
Details of the system:

No iron step up transformer is connected yet (for H bridge testing reasons).

Dead time is at 1 μs (for test reasons the plan is to decrease at 500ns if switching speed will allows that).

Driver IC IR2113S. (From egs002 module)

Totem pole gate driver amplifier 7 A with complementary MOSFETs (photo attached)

Power MOSFETs FDH055N15A (6 in parallel).

Rg is 6.8 Ω (for each MOSFET).

Rgs is 33 kΩ (for each MOSFET).

I use antiparallel diodes for each one.

V drive at 16,5 V

SPWM signal output speed after IR2113 is about 70 ns rise and falls at the totem pole input.

H bridge voltage bus is 60 V. (work from 45 to 60 V range)


In the photo I upload we see the high side MOSFET gate curve without any load at H bridge.
The oscilloscope at photo shows clearly the times and voltages.
The ask is:

What is the best choice to choose for better efficiency and safety at switching  between the two?

Is this switching speeds ok to work on 60 V, and pass 30-40 A at each MOSFET?


Thank you in advance!

Wasn't this question posted yesterday?

@oroperio Please do not delete and repost.

I re edit but the post was locked.So,Site suggestion is to delete and post again.

Where did you find said "Site suggestions"?

I am newbie to this site and I didn't understand well how can i unlock the post again after the re edit,so i find an second option to delete and post again.
